# Trying To The Player Attack While Moving

Tags: gml, game-maker-studio-2

I tried all the ways i found and none work please help.
I want the player to attack while moving its that simple but i cant do it for some reason. I'm new to Game Maker Language!

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you've got? I may eventually help with this.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a sprite(like a dragon)
2. create 4 layers of that sprite(**1:** Stable dragon, **2:** Dragon charging breath + ready to flap, **3:** dragon firing + flapping, **4:** dragon fired + flapped)
3. create an object for that sprite
4. create a **create** event and drag code
5. use these: `image_index = 0; image_speed = 0;` + in **movement**; **gravity** event( angle -90, power : 1)
6. Create a **global left click** event and use this code :
   `if(image_index == 0){image_speed = .3; "create a fireball etc" vspeed = 10; hspeed = 10; }`
7. Create a **Animation End** event in **other** and use these :

   image_index = 0; image_speed = 0;

this is an easy way to make a dragon which moves like a flappy bird while shooting fireballs. You can sample this to create a moving object who shoots.